# Trying to recover a Mac time capsule sparsebundle

Tags: macos-highsierra

Looking for some help recovering my time machine backup! I lost the HDD on my iMac and have now replaced it with a 4TB SSD. I tried to recover the backup from my NAS (Netgear) time machine, but it turned out to be corrupt and inaccessible.

I have managed to recover most of it using Disk Warrior 5 and can now mount the Time Machine Backup image and access the backup package. I can see numerous backups, but the ”Macintosh HD” folder is greyed out and no matter what I do I can’t seem to get access to them.

I have tried changing ownership, reseting ACL etc all to no avail! I copied the .sparsebundle to an external drive and reconnected to time machine and activated backups.

It has made some further backups today and when I mount the disk I can access the backup folders from today, but all previous folders are still greyed out!

I have managed to get one of the previous Macintosh HD folders accessible, but no idea how I did it!!

I have examined the folders in question and compared them to the working folders using ls -le and all the attributes look the same with the exception of the numbers listed after the permissions attributes.

So for the new accessible folders the attributes are: drwxr-xr-x@ 17 root wheel 884 “date” Macintosh HD

For the older greyed out inaccessible folders the attributes are: drwxr-xr-x@ 7 root wheel 374 “date” Macintosh HD

And for the folder I somehow managed to recover, the attributes are: drwxr-xr-x@ 11 root wheel 612 “date” Macintosh HD

Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree and I can’t recover the older backups this way? Any help appreciated

Regards

Philyerboots

Comment: Have you tried just setting the entire external drive to Ignore Ownership?

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried taking ownership, but still no access to the Macintosh HD folders.

Comment: Not *taking* ownership, *ignoring* ownership. Get Info on the whole volume, there's a check box at the bottom. https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnGXy.png

Comment: I can't ignore ownership as the drive contains a time machine backup up and because of this the "ignore ownership" checkbox doesn't appear when you select get info.